Twilio sends whatsApp template message, but user doesn't receive it
I'm developing an API using Spring that includes the functionality to start a conversation with a user via WhatsApp. I’m following the Twilio documentation, but the message isn’t reaching the user’s WhatsApp. The log doesn’t return any errors, so I’m unsure what’s going wrong.
Here’s the relevant code snippet:
Message message1 = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + salesManWhatsapp), new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + companyWhatsapp),
                    TEMPLATE_SID)
            .setContentSid(TEMPLATE_SID)
            .setContentVariables(contentVariables)
            .setMessagingServiceSid(MESSAGING_SID)
            .create();

The big problem here is that Twilio is accepting my request, so I don't know where I am making a mistake.
I tried a lot of things, put the messaging sid in the "from" field of the creator, using different combinations and etc.

This is the intended behavior as Twilio only confirms that it received your request. You will get a message SID in return for this call, and the message logs should show you whether the message has been delivered successfully and, if not, what the problem was. Check out the Debugging Tools in the console to find the details and add them to the question above
